# Oracle - get data from first day of previous month at particular time to first day of current month at particular time

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is to get the data of a particular date range in Oracle as follows -

```
CompletedDate = Range between First Day of Previous Month @12:00AM to First Day of Current Month @4:00PM
```

And also

```
CompleteDate = Range between previous Friday at 4:31 PM and current Friday at 4:30 PM
```

Can you please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be

```
select *
from your_table
where date_column between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) 
                      and trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 16/24
```

and

```
select *
from your_table
where date_column between next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRIDAY') - 7 + 16/24 + 31/(24*60)
                      and next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRIDAY') + 16/24 + 30/(24*60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
where (CompleteDate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -1)  and
       CompleteDate < trunc(sysdate, 'MON')
      ) or
      (CompleteDate < next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRIDAY') + interval '14' hour + interval '30' minute and
       CompleteDate > next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRIDAY') - interval '7' day + interval '14' hour + interval '30' minute
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date operations as follows:

```
--scenario 1
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'), -1) 
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON') + INTERVAL '16' HOUR;

--scenario 2
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '8' DAY,'FRI') 
                          + INTERVAL '16' HOUR + INTERVAL '31' MINUTE 
    AND NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,'FRI') + INTERVAL '16' HOUR;
```